Is there a feature in Dart to cause variable's type promotion after a function call similar to TypeScript's "type predicates"?
Is there any way to achieve variable type promotion in dart (annotate a function to return "is of type" value instead of plain bool, similar to TypeScript's type predicates) or do I have to use null check operators?
In dart, I frequently have situations, where I have to check if function's received parameter is null or an empty String/Iterable/Map. Places, where either null or an empty value has to be treated the same way, instead of writing if (value != null && value.isNotEmpty) ... I created an extension on String, Iterable and Map types with isTruthy getter function that has null equality and isNotEmpty checks inside it. For example, extension on String? type looks like this:
extension MaybeStringExtension on String? {
  /// Returns `false` if it is `null` or an empty string, `true` otherwise.
  bool get isTruthy => this != null && this!.isNotEmpty;
}

The problem is, after this isTruthy check in some other function, the variable doesn't get promoted from type String? to String and dart analyzer complains with "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'." error if I dont add the null check operator '!'. For example:
bool isValidPassword(String? value) {
  // This way value gets promoted to type `String` and don't have to add `!` operator.
  return value != null && value.isNotEmpty && passwordRegExp.hasMatch(value);

  // This way value doesn't get promoted to type `String` and have to add `!` operator.
  return value.isTruthy && passwordRegExp.hasMatch(value!);
}

In TypeScript, functions can return type predicates that promote variable type after calling them, for example:
function isTruthy(value: string | null) : value is string {
  return value != null && value.length != 0;
}

function someOtherFunc(value: string | null) {
  if (isTruthy(value)) value.charAt(0); // value is of type string here
}


You're about to do a regex match.  Why do you even have the .isNotEmpty there?  Your code really needs only distinguish null from a String that may or may not match.

You could do this with a pattern match easily enough:
bool isValidPassword(String? input) => switch(input) {
  String s? when passwordRegExp.hasMatch(s) => true,
  _ => false,
};


actually, didn't need the when.  could have returned the hasMatch call instead.  s would have already been promoted.

No. There is no feature in Dart that allows promotion to escape the scope where the comparison happened.
Dart can sometimes remember promotions associated with boolean values, but only later in the same function.
I'd recommend a function which returns null if the input is empty.
extension NullableStrings on String? {
  String? get emptyAsNull => "" == this ? null : this;
  String get nullAsEmpty => this ?? "";
  bool matchesPattern(Pattern pattern) => switch (this?.indexOf(pattern)) {
    != null && >= 0 => true,
    _ => false,
  };
}

and then check that:
bool isValidPassword(String? input) =>
   input.emptyAsNull.matchesPattern(_passwordRegExp);

That said, I don't see anything wrong with the original code.
Doing input != null && input.isNotEmpty && ... is a perfectly fine way to start if the input is nullable. You always need to do something to get rid of null before you start working. That the empty string is also special here, is not related to nullability.
I'd rather as why the input is nullable to begin with. Why is "no input" not provided as an empty string? Why is the function called at all, if the input is null?

Thanks for the suggestion.
As to why the function is being called with a null value, I'm using them in Flutter's TextFormField.validator functions, and they take in a String? as an input.
